# Search for machines with a role in a chef environment

Tags: chef-infra

I'm looking for a way to search for nodes that have the same role and are part of the same environment.

Outside the recipe, the normal way is:

```
 knife search "chef_environment:STG AND role:elasticsearch" -i
```

Inside a recipe, I only found that you can search for one thing like in:

```
hosts = search(:node, 'role:elasticsearch')
```

So how?

Thank you,

Comment: So what's the question? Have you tried the `search` method as you described? Looked at its [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html)? The `knife search` command as you listed it defaults to the `node` index, that's why you don't have to specify it there (but could also be `knife search node "chef.."`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I would want is to have the result of search for nodes that are on a certain environment and a certain role in a 'hosts' variable.

Comment: So what's the problem? Is `search(:node, 'chef_environment:STG AND role:elasticsearch')` not working?

Comment: Well... this is embarrassing. I didn't know how to run an nested search in the recipe. Your last answer solved my mystery. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the future, the example given is mostly fine but should use the query `roles:elasticsearch` instead of the singular `role:`. While both seem to work, the plural form has a lot fewer "gotchas".

Comment: I find `roles:name` returns no results, whereas `role:name` returns results correctly.